# Macro for changing font and its size

Tags: fontsize, context

I'm trying out Context and have hit a bump. I need to create a macro which inserts a symbol from another font at a different size in the running text. I'm done this in XeLaTeX before but I'm having trouble doing this in Context.

The following is my MWE (ConTeXt):

```
\definefont[sakkal][name:Sakkal Majalla at 36pt]

\def\mySakkal{{\sakkal TEST}}

\starttext

This is normal text and this is \mySakkal{} which should be bigger.

\stoptext
```

The font does change but the font size does not. My ConTeXt version is `2016.05.17 19:20`.

For reference, here is the MWE in in XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\newfontfamily\sakkalfont[
Script=Arabic,%
Numbers=Proportional,%
Scale=2.0,%
]{Sakkal Majalla}

\newcommand{\mySakkal}{{\sakkalfont{TEST}}}

\begin{document}
This is regular text and this is \mySakkal{} which should be bigger.
\end{document}
```

The following is the results of both.

[image: Output Results]

Comment: Your example gives the expected result here with the latest context version (2016.11.04 20:50), the fontsize changes. Which version are you using? Btw, you can scale the font relative to its surrounding size with the syntax \definefont[sakkal][name:Sakkal Majalla sa 1.2] (I assume that's what you xelatex syntax does, though I am not sure).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I've updated the MWE to show both and also the output for each. My ConTeXt version is `2016.05.17 19:20`. I'm using TeXLive 2016.

Comment: @KhalidHussain The ConTeXt releases don't necessarily make it into TeX Live: you are best grabbing their 'minimals' distribution

Comment: @JosephWright, whose 'minimals'? TeX Live or ConTeXt? I'm going to try updating TeX Live to see if that helps.

Comment: @KhalidHussain http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone As I said, ConTeXt releases don't necessarily go into TL (They don't go to CTAN).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The devil is in the details.

After spending mobile bandwidth downloading the latest ConTeXt and just barely getting it running, I was met with the same problem.

The space in the middle of the font name was causing the problem.

The following works perfectly:

```
\definefont[sakkal][name:SakkalMajalla at 36pt]

\def\mySakkal{{\sakkal TEST}}

\starttext

This is normal text and this is \mySakkal{} which should be bigger.

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 2):

I tested your example with ConTeXt from texlive, and I get the expected output again. Are you sure ConTeXt finds your font file?Here is my output, with indication of the version used (I use the `file` syntax for specifying the font instead of `name` because I didn't want to install it, but that shouldn't make any difference):

[image]

Comment: Just tried out your method. Yes it works if I use `file` instead of `name`. I copied the font out of the Fonts folder and tested it. That's weird.